# Typescript error Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

I'm need help with fix error in my code:

```
export class BSPTree {
    leaf: Box;
    lchild: undefined;
    rchild: undefined;

    constructor(leaf: Box){
        this.leaf = leaf;
    }


    getLeafs(){
        if (this.lchild === undefined && this.rchild === undefined)
            return [this.leaf]
        else
            return [].concat(this.lchild.getLeafs(), this.rchild.getLeafs())
    }
```

Why do I get this mistake?

Comment: Because the else condition could be met if one of `lchild` or `rchild` is undefined (DeMorgan)

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: You handle the case where one of them is undefined. I don't know your business logic, but it would make sense just to change the first condition && to an || to return the leaf whenever one of the children are undefined, but the specifics are up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define types of `lchild` and `rchild` and also solve their case when they are `undefined`.

```js
export class BSPTree {
    leaf: Box;

    lchild: undefined | BSPTree; // <- here
    rchild: undefined | BSPTree; // <- here

    constructor(leaf: Box){
        this.leaf = leaf;
    }


    getLeafs(){
        if (this.lchild === undefined && this.rchild === undefined)
            return [this.leaf]
        else
            return [].concat(this.lchild?.getLeafs() || [], this.rchild?.getLeafs() || []) // <- here ?
    }
```

Comment: Note that this will concat `undefined` to the array (since the optionals evaluate to undefined)... I don't think that's exactly what's desired here.

Comment: Is it a sample how to solve it, perhaps the author doesn't use TS 3.7. I've added `|| []`